# Can I have a declaration in C++ like `myFunction(void *x, void *y)`?

Tags: c++

Can I have a declaration in C++ like `myFunction(void *x, void *y)`?

I have a (big) project with this declaration, looks like it works, but I don't understand how can I have a "void" as parameter type. Would it be the same as just `myFunction(*x, *y)`?

Comment: Do you really not have a return type specified? In c++, you can only omit that for constructors and destructors.

Comment: C as a language lets you do practically anything (as it is very like a long hand assembler). As an extension so does C++. The real question you should be asking yourself is "Is this a good idea" and if the answer is no then "What is a better way to achieve this goal".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a `void` parameter type, but a `void*` - a pointer-to-void. Any pointer can be implicitly converted to a pointer-to-void, but you can't do anything useful with a `void*` alone. What does the definition of one of those functions look like?

Comment: The definition makes a casting to a type and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can have such functions.

In fact, C library has lots of function which has `void*` as parameter types. Such as:

- [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/)
- [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/)
- [memchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memchr/)
- [memmove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/)
- [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/)

Mostly such functions either cast the arguments into some type, usually `char*`, then it works on it.

Similarly, there are other APIs such as POSIX's `pcreate_thread` or WIN32's `CreateThread` has few parameters of `void*`.  It is because they can be work generically with any type.

But in C++, you rarely need `void*` as parameter type, except of course when you use C APIs. In C++, for genericity, you use template which is typesafe.